# Should I include mini projects in my resume as a fresher?

Tags: resume, software-industry, recruitment, projects, fresher

I am a university fresher in Information Technology. As a fresher, I have nothing to show as my experience in my resume. But, I have done some academic projects during my study. Some of them are medium sized like 'Job Portal' and and 'A programmer's text editor'. Some of them are very small like 'Animation in C graphics' and 'Remote database connection for Android application'. I have also Git repositories to show the proof of my projects.

Can anyone guide me that should I include these mini projects in my resume? Or should I only include medium sized projects but not include small sized projects to keep resume concise?

Comment: any thing which qualifies as a weekly assignment and does not qualify as a project should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When including projects in your resume try to be as objective as possible - if in doubt whether a project is worth mentioning or not you could simply add links to your Github repos and talk about them on the interview itself.

If those "mini" projects are suitable for the organization you're sending your resume to, then go ahead and add them. Also, if they are not in your main expertise, adding them would show your potential employers you have a broad area of interests.

For example:

> I'm a backend developer, but I usually add small "front-end" projects like simple CSS animations and stuff. This shows that while I'm a backend expert I also like and am capable of doing frontend tasks.

One last thing - you could also add any certificates in MOOC or any other training, related in any way with the position you're applying for. It would give a hint to what your interests are.

I tend to prepare my resumes specifically for the organization/position I'm applying - I would start with a very brief "cover letter", explaining my motivations and interest in the job, then I'd add links to some of my projects and activities and would finish with skills and expertise. This way I make the HR's job easier and prepare them on what we can talk in a face-to-face meeting.

So in short - keep your resume as short and informative as possible; leave the talking for the interview itself. And always update your resume depending on the position/organization you're applying for.

Comment: +1 for preparing a resume on a per position base. Some small projects might be relevant for one position, but not for the next one.

Comment: I would avoid using the word "stuff" in a resumé, but that's just me. If you have several concrete examples, list more than one, and tailor the list to the position. ("Such as for example ABC, FGH and XYZ.") If you only have one, don't claim to have more and lump it together as "ABC and stuff". *Be specific!*

Answer (score 2):

Its fine to mention your medium - large and even small **projects** but the key word is project. The work you mention should qualify as project not as an assignment. Making a database connection is something which will certainly not qualify as a project.

What you have mentioned as mini projects are very basic stuff done many times in a project.You can bring them up in interview session but mentioning them in resume will not be a nice idea.